# Constructing a regex to match filenames from of file paths

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list with various file paths

e.g:

```
changed_files = ['/home/file1.txt', '/home/test/file2.cls', 'home/file3.cls', '/home/file5.cls2', '/user/bin/cls/test.txt']
```

I want to get file names with the extension .cls using regex
Output I want is

```
['file2','file3']
```

I am trying to use this regex:-

```
r = re.compile("([^/.]+)\.[^.]*$", re.MULTILINE)
newlist = list(filter(r.match, changed_files))
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Why use a hand-crafted regex? Why not construct a [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) instance from each string, and the filter [by properties you want](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#accessing-individual-parts), like `.name` or `.suffix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using regex.

```
changed_files = ['/home/file1.txt', '/home/test/file2.cls', 'home/file3.cls', '/home/file5.cls2', '/user/bin/cls/test.txt']
[x.group(1) for i in changed_files if (x:=re.search(r'(\w+)\.cls\b',i))]
# ['file2', 'file3']
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/DiligentTraumaticPatch) here.

Comment: This is an optimised answer.
Thanks @Ch3steR

Comment: @Mr.Axe Added demo to answer...If it helped please upvote and accept this as answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with condition

```
cls_files = [
    file.split('/')[-1].rstrip('.cls') for file in changed_files if file.endswith('.cls')
]
```

Output

```
['file2', 'file3']
```

Comment: Instead of spliting again at `.` you just use `.strip`

Comment: @Vishnudev
Thanks

This solution works but it also matches some unwanted files if their extension is like 
.cls2 or .cls-xml-meta.

Comment: Please mention them in the post. Updated my answer. @Mr.Axe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, something like this will work:

```
txt = ['/home/file1.txt', 'home/test/file2.cls', 'home/file3.cls']
finalList = []
for item in txt:
  if re.search(".cls$", item):
    formattedName = item.split('/')[-1].split('.cls')[0]
    finalList.append(formattedName)

print(finalList)
```

Comment: @Mr.Axe Glad to know! :)

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
r = re.compile("/\w+\.cls$")
res = [file.split('/')[-1].rstrip('.cls') for file in changed_files  if re.findall(r, file)]
```

ouput:

```
['file2', 'file3']
```

Comment: This answer works but doesn't seem to explain to the OP why it works/how it does. Could it elaborate a little?

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review. Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary in the answer for why this is the correct answer.